# Getting list of tags for a user from google reader api

Tags: google-reader

Form [this](http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/2005/12/google-reader-api.html) blog post  i see that once you know the tag name you can items in the tag 
by

```
/reader/atom/user/[user id]/label/[tag]
```

But how do i know what tags are available for the user ? 
How can get the list of available tags for a user from google reader api .

I've seen third party apps do that, not sure how they are doing it .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to use the List API which requires you to be authenticated as the user for whom you want the tags. To authenticate you'll need an SID and a token. To get these, first send a GET request to 
https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?service=reader&Email= [your Google username] &Passwd= [your Google password]

which will return an SID, LSID and a UserID in the format key=value\nkey=value\nkey=value. You only need the SID.

Now you want to put the SID into a cookie that looks like
Name: SID
Value: [your SID]
Path: /
Domain: .google.com

Now using this cookie send a GET request to http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/token which returns your token in plain text. You won't actually need a token for this particular method but it's useful to keep.

The List API method for grabbing a list of tags is
http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/tag/list?output=json&ck=1250374215987&client=scroll

which will return a JSON formatted list of tags. The ck argument is the current Unix time, so set it appropriately.

For more detailed information on authenticating with the Google Reader API have a look at my recent [blog entry](http://blog.martindoms.com/2009/08/15/using-the-google-reader-api-part-1/) on the topic.